# Valor não está sendo levado via POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

No `index.php` tem 1 campo `input` que envia um valor por `ajax`, que deve ser lido pelo `cdb.php`.

index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#formulario").on("submit", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var cdb = $("#cdb").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "cdb.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: cdb
                }).done(function(data){
                    $("#cdb").val("");
                    $("#cdb").focus();
                    listar();
                }).fail(function(data){
                    alert("Erro");
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

...

```
<form id="formulario" method="POST" action="" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div>
            <?php echo rand(1, 100) ?>
            <input id="cdb" type="text" name="cdb" class="validate" required autofocus onfocus="this.value='';">
            <button type="submit">GRAVAR</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

cdb.php

```
$cdb = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'cdb');
```

Comment: No pedido ajax tenta o seguinte: `data: {cdb: cdb},`. no cdb.php faz `echo 'YOO ' .$_POST['cdb'];die();` a ver se retorna isso como resposta

Comment: @Miguel só coloquei `data: {cdb: cdb}` e deu certo ! Poderia por favor publicar a resposta e explicar porque de ter que fazer dessa forma ? Muito obrigado !

Comment: Não consigo agora, estou no carro, mas acredito que algum colega possa fazer esse favor

Comment: Essa requisição leva pra um controller php certo?

Comment: @Miguel tranquilo ! Já responderam ! Mas agradeço a atenção !

Comment: Gabriel, não tem controller, é só um script básico mesmo ! Mas obrigado !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o você esta passando uma informação sem referência nenhuma. A propriedade `data` do `ajax` recebe um `array` do tipo `key` e `value`, ou seja, para cada item é necessário ter uma chave e um valor, no seu código você só está passando o valor de `cdb`, para passar a chave também você poderia fazer algo como:

```
$("#formulario").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var cdb = $("#cdb").val();
    $.ajax({
    url: "cdb.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {
            cdb: cdb
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#cdb").val("");
        $("#cdb").focus();
        listar();
    }).fail(function(data){
        alert("Erro");
    });
});
```

Mas e se seu formulário tivesse mais campos, você teria que fazer um por um. Para nossa alegria existe uma função que é responsável por pegar todos os campos de um formulário e transformar em um array do tipo `key` e `value`, no caso o `key` será a propriedade `name` do campo e `value` será o próprio `value` do campo. Essa função é a `serialize()` para usa-lá seria simplesmente assim:

```
$("#formulario").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var cdb = $("#cdb").val();
    $.ajax({
    url: "cdb.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: $("#formulario").serialize()
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#cdb").val("");
        $("#cdb").focus();
        listar();
    }).fail(function(data){
        alert("Erro");
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfeito cara ! Esse tipo de resposta com complementos fundamentais (serialize) são demais ! Parabéns e obrigado !